# range.copy method throwing unexpected error

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have the following code to copy data between 2 different excel files

```
xlRangeSource = xlsheetSource.Range("B2:K" & IntAmountOfRows)
xlRangeTarget = xlsheetTarget.Range("A" & intStartOfEmptyRow)
xlRangeSource.Copy(Destination:=xlWbTarget.Worksheets(xlsheetTarget).range(xlRangeTarget))
```

`IntAmountOfRows` and `intStartOfEmptyRow` are both integers

When executing my code, I get the following error:

```
Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))
```

However, I am using a range to copy to a range. I don't understand why the types are a mismatch

Comment: I think that you have got quite a few answers on this matter. Not sure why you keep trying alternatives. Use the code which works fine and just focus on coming up with an algorithm delivering what you want; that is: `sourceRange.Copy()` and `targetRange.PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteValues)` (or the pasting type you want).

Comment: @varocarbas I understand, but this question was pretty much for my own learning purposes. 

Currently, I am looking into ways to copy my data without using my clipboard

Comment: Copying your data without using the clipboard? In Widows? This is not possible. In any case, it seems like you are not intending to avoid the clipboard but to reduce the length of the code (the fact of putting everything on the same line does not imply a simplification in the actions being performed; one-line codes can be very computational expensive because of calling complex functions). Every time you call a Copy method under Windows involving files, you would use the clipboard. If you don't want to use the clipboard, you might store the information in a temporary location...

Comment: ... but this would be much slower. The whole point of the clipboard is precisely setting an easily-accessible temporary location for transferring information. I recommend you to stop wasting time on intending to optimise what cannot be optimised; and focus your efforts on optimising what, most likely, is highly optimisable: your algorith, the I/O system, etc.

Comment: @varocarbas Aah thank you! A colleague of mine (whom I work for) told me I could avoid the `"There is an awful amount of data on the clipboard, do you want to keep this?"` message by using the `copy( Destination :=)` method

Comment: No, you cannot. But the clipboard should be enough to deal with any (acceptable) amount of data (perhaps it is better relying on the whole worksheet rather than on specific ranges on this front). Note that you can affect its properties through the Clipboard Class. In case of having too much data for the clipboard (unlikely) and not being able to copy the whole worksheet (adding it to the target workbook), you might split the information and perform various actions: iterate through all the cells with a loop and copy/paste (or set the destination Value property) the sub-ranges you want.

Comment: @varocarbas Ah yes, I see. Like you said; It's not really a huge problem, currently I just ignore the popups with `Displayalerts = false`

Comment: OK. But it might be indicative that you are not doing things too well on this front. Perhaps you should intend to optimise this part further (in any of the suggested ways). I told you some time ago already: Office interop allows many options for virtually anything but not all of them work or deliver the best accuracy possible; better sticking to something working fine for you and just trying to optimise the whole algorithm around it. If you want to use Copy/Paste, the aforementioned code works fine and delivers all what you need on this front; so... why changing it?

Comment: @varocarbas I have not changed it! The application works as intended. However, I was merely trying to optimise my application for a version 2.0 by trying new things

Comment: I understand that and that's why I have explained you how to deal with improvements in Office Interop: use an alternative which works for you (in this case: Copy() PasteSpecial(method)) and don't change it; if you want to optimise the code further, look at the way in which this code is used and if it might be replaced/improved (e.g., instead of copying thousands of cells, copying the whole worksheet). If you don't know how to do that, post your conditions and your code and request help.

Comment: Sub test()Dim A As Range Dim B As Range Set A = Range("A1:A5") Set B = Range("B1:B5") A.Copy Destination:=B End Sub

Copying your data without clipboard may be not possible but isnt it possible to work with pointers. When you 'SET' your range as an object variable you could just work with the pointer on the stack not with the managed heap object. The problem with working with the clipboard is (according to my experience) when u have long macros and provide other operations while the macro is running sometimes the clipboard content is messed up.